# Proper way to use import, when calling external function

Tags: python

I have a flask server, that when an endpoint is triggered, it calls a function in another python file.

I use `import myFile` in my server, in order to call the function located inside `myFile.py`.

But above the function there are some imports.

Is it correct to place these imports in the external `.py` file, or should these be placed in the `server.py`?

If they are in the `server.py`, i don't know if the function in `myFile.py` will be able to see them.

If they are in `myFile.py`, then are they being imported everytime that the function is called?

Where is the correct file, to place them?

Comment: Each Python module needs to include the imports that it needs.  You don't have to go import what it needs.  The imports in `myFile.py` will happen when you do `import myFile`.  Calling the function doesn't change that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should place the imports in `myFile.py`. Otherwise, just as you've guessed, the function wouldn't be able to access them, as it can't see beyond its namespace.

You don't need to worry about the imports running every time you call the function - they run once, at the `import` statement, and from there on it's as if everything you've imported was written inside the `server.py` file.